# Iterate though array of object in java

Tags: java

I am trying to loop over the array of objects in java. I'm posting this value from client side to server side which is java.

```
"userList": [{
  "id": "id1",
  "name": "name1"
},
{
  "id": "id2",
  "name": "name2"
}]
```

Now I want to get the value of each id and name. I tried the code below:

```
   for (Object temp : userList) 
       System.out.print(temp);
       System.out.print(temp.getId());
   }
```

But the output I get is:`[object Object]`

I'm sorry for this stupid question. But how will I get the value of id and name?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't Javascript?

Comment: Convert your object to JSONObject first.

Comment: @Zero you need to cast the object to the modal class before you start using your object

Comment: using jackson data binding you will be able to implement a neat solution
[link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jackson/jackson_data_binding.htm)

Comment: Your need to follow the rules of polymorphism before using object

Answer (score 1):

You're getting `[object Object]` because you didn't turn your JavaScript object into JSON on the client side before sending it to your server--you need to use something like `JSON.stringify(object)` in the browser.

Next, you will need to unpack your JSON into some sort of Java structure. The preferable way to do this is to let an existing tool such as Jackson or Gson map it onto a Java object that looks like:

```
class User {
    String id;
    String name;
}
```

How to do this will depend on your framework, but Spring MVC (for example) supports it mostly automatically.

Comment: Don't think this is javascript since it wasn't a tag for the post. I think it's just a `String()` representation of a json string

Comment: @j.seashell The `[object Object]` is a **dead** giveaway that it's JavaScript. (There's also a question about deserializing on the Java end, but the sending JavaScript has to be fixed first.)

Comment: what chrylis is saying is right. You need to follow steps to achieve a specific result you cannot skip steps. And I see there are some stupid people who are makring the response by negative vote

Answer (score 0):

Implement the `toString` method for your class according to how you want the printed output to look.

For example...

```
public class User {
    private String id;
    private String name;

    // Constructors, field accessors/mutators, etc...

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("User {id: %s, name: %s}", this.id, this.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted? This is exactly what I would do. Override `toString()`. `System.out.println()` will call `toString()` on `temp`. That's what system out does. +1

Comment: @j.seashell Downvoted because if this were a Java problem, the output would be `some.Class@123abcd`. `[object Object]` is a characteristic indicator that `toString()` is being called *in JavaScript*.

Comment: someone has been downvoting all the response LOL

Comment: @chrylis thanks for the info. Javascript definitely isn't something I've spent much time with, which is why i just made the assumption about what `[object Object]` was. Up'd for your helpfulness

Comment: @chrylis Yes, that's why I asked in the original question whether this was actually a Javascript problem. However, there is java code in it as well (System.out.print).

Answer (score -1):

Your question does not have complete information. You certainly are skipping steps.

Before you start using the object in java you need to cast the object.

```
ArrayList<User> convertedUserList = (ArrayList<User>)userList;
for (User temp : convertedUserList) 
    System.out.print(temp);
    System.out.print(temp.getId());
}
```

Comment: If you have to complain about something, then do this either on meta or at least in a comment. Keep the answer itself clean.